Error al llamar a WebApi desde Blazor Web App: '<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0
Sigo probando Blazor Web App con Web API y me he encontrado con otro problema.
Tengo el siguiente Web API
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using GestionInternado.Shared.Models;
using GestionInternado.Shared.ViewModels;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace GestionCasaMadre.Server.Controllers
  {
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  [Authorize]

  public class CursosController : ControllerBase
    {
    private readonly J2GestionInternadoContext _context;

    public CursosController(J2GestionInternadoContext context)
      {
      _context = context;
      }
[HttpGet]
[Route("TodosCursosInternado")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CursoViewModel>>> GetTodosCursosInternado()
  {
  List<Curso> cursos = await _context.Cursos.ToListAsync();
  List<CursoViewModel> cursosvm = cursos.Select(s => new CursoViewModel
    {
    Id = s.Id,IdEtapa = "",NombreCurso = s.NombreCurso}).Distinct().ToList();
return cursosvm;
}
}

Y lo llamo desde la pagina counter que la he adaptado un poco:
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IJSRuntime JS
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CargaCursos">Cursos</button>
<p>@estado</p>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    string estado = "";
    private List<CursoViewModel>? cursos = new List<CursoViewModel>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
        await this.CargaCursos();
        }
    protected async Task CargaCursos()
        {
        estado = "Cargando datos";
        try
            {
            cursos = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<CursoViewModel>>("/api/Cursos/TodosCursosInternado");
            estado = "";
            }
        catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
            {
            exception.Redirect();
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            estado = ex.Message;
            }
        }

    private void IncrementCount()
        {
        currentCount++;
        }
}

Tal y como esta ejecuto la aplicación, entro un counter, me redirige al login, meto los datos y ejecuta dos veces OnInitializedAsync, la primera vez que se ejecuta ni entra en el webapi ni nada, salta una excepcion:
'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0

Automaticamente vuelve a ejecutarse y ya se trae los datos bien.
Si directamente en el navegador pongo https://localhost:1234/api/Cursos/TodosCursosInternado me redirige al login, entra en el webapi y devuelve el json correctamente.
Si comento en el web api la linea   [Authorize], entonces no falla nunca y recoge los datos del web api.
Alguien sabe porque ocurre esto? una ayudita?
Gracias
Acabo de descubrir que lo que ocurre es que la primera vez que entra en Counter y llama al webapi, lo que devuelve el webapi es la pagina de login, la primera vez que invoca al webapi no coge los datos del login de la pagina, aunque este autentificado, pero al recargar si que coge los datos del usuario sin hacer nada.
